# Referencing an extended class from inside the base class in PHP

Tags: php, class, oop

Sorry for perhaps not the most accurate title. I'm having trouble figuring out what this would even be called.

I'm somewhat new to OOP with php, as most of my time is spent with procedural programming. In an effort to better learn these concepts, I'm taking an existing application and rewriting portions of it using OOP.  The below example is how I set up the base class, and then I extended the base class into several smaller classes for easier maintainability. Below, you can see how I extended the base class to create a user class.  **Please note, that my class definitions are in separate files, but I have a working autoloader that automatically registers them**

```
class EventScheduler{
    function __construct(){
       // set up database connections here
    } 
}

class User extends EventScheduler{
    private function getUserProfile($username){
       // return an array here representing
       // details of passed username from database
    }

    public function getUserType($username){
        return $this->getUserProfile($username)['user_type'];
    }
}
```

What I'd **like** to be able to do is reference the User class from inside the base class, like this:

```
$eventApp = new EventScheduler();
$userType = $eventApp->User->getUserProfile("nameHere");
```

What I'm currently doing is this:

```
$eventApp = new EventScheduler();
 //do some stuff here using the base class

$users = new User();
$userType = $users->getUserProfile("nameHere");
```

But as I add more child classes, I don't want to have to instantiate every extended class like I did there, I'd like to have them all grouped under the base object, rather than having each extended class in it's own object.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want to do.  "I'd like to be able to do is reference the User class from inside the base class" - this defeats the purpose of extending classes. If you need the child class' methods in the base class, put the method in the base class.

Comment: In trying to understand what you are doing... In proper object oriented design, a parent class has no concept of the extended (children) classes. If you want the parent class to have some functionality from the children, you define an abstract method in the parent class that is required to be implemented by all children.

Comment: If I put my additional user functions inside my base class, I'd have a huge base class with no good logical separation. Is there anyway to separate the logic into different sections within the base class.  Id basically want to separate things into users, rooms, buildings, equipment, and events.

Comment: In what way should Users and Rooms extend from the same class? Why would Rooms and Buildings extend from the same class? Rooms are contained in Buildings. This is clearly a case of "You are doing it wrong."

Comment: I'm sure you're right. There is a permission layer that sits on top that allows only certain users permissions to modify or reserve rooms in certain buildings.  This would be much simpler to do away with the classes and just go with pure function calls; separating similar functions into each of their own include files.

Comment: A `User` should never extend a `EventScheduler`. They are completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is

```
$users = new User();

//do some stuff here using the base class
// ie $users->someFunctionFromEventScheduler();

$userType = $users->getUserProfile("nameHere");
```

Comment: This example, paired with the comment with @kainaw makes perfect sense.  It accomplishes what I was trying to do, however, seeing it this way tells me that it wouldn't be a proper way of addressing the base class, and can end up being really confusing later.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good reason to start reading up on common design patterns in OOP. There are plenty of good resources for this online and a quick google search will yield plenty of results and examples mostly hosted on github.

The specific pattern I believe you are looking for is the mediator pattern ([Mediator pattern example in PHP](https://github.com/domnikl/DesignPatternsPHP/blob/master/Behavioral/Mediator/Mediator.php)). Rather than extending a class, as you are doing in your example, the mediator pattern is useful when you want an instance of a class that has access to many other classes that can all communicate with each other through one base class. The premise is that 'One good friend is better than many acquaintances.`.

An example for you: (interfaces are incredibly useful here as they define specific characteristics that are required in each of the classes)

```
/**
 * Interface Mediator
 */
interface Mediator {
    /**
     * @param string    $key
     * @param Mediated  $mediated
     * @return void
     */
    public function attach($key, Mediated $mediated);

    /**
     * @param $key
     * @return Mediated
     */
    public function getAttached($key);
}

/**
 * Interface Mediated
 */
interface Mediated {
    /**
     * @param Mediator $mediator
     * @return void
     */
    public function setMediator(Mediator $mediator);

    /**
     * @return Mediator
     */
    public function getMediator();
}
```

Now we need a base mediator class, I'll use your event scheduler example. Notice that it implements the `Mediator` interface and must, as a result implement the methods the interface requires.

```
/**
 * Class EventScheduler
 */
class EventScheduler implements Mediator {

    /**
     * A collection of mediated instances.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $mediated = [];

    /**
     * @param string $key
     * @param Mediated $mediated
     * @return void
     */
    public function attach($key, Mediated $mediated)
    {
        // So upon attaching a mediated instance we can build the two
        // way binding in one place using the key as the identifier.
        // First we set $this on the mediated instance.
        $mediated->setMediator($this);

        // Then we add this instance to our mediated array inside this instance
        $this->mediated[$key] = $mediated;
    }

    /**
     * @param $key
     * @return Mediated
     */
    public function getAttached($key)
    {
        return $this->mediated[$key];
    }
}
```

Now we can setup a mediated instance. That can be attached to the mediator. Notice it implements the `Mediated` interface.

```
/**
 * Class User
 */
class User implements Mediated {

    /**
     * @var Mediator
     */
    protected $mediator;

    /**
     * @param Mediator $mediator
     * @return void
     */
    public function setMediator(Mediator $mediator)
    {
        $this->mediator = $mediator;
    }

    /**
     * @return Mediator
     */
    public function getMediator()
    {
        return $this->mediator;
    }
}
```

You can create as many of the mediated instances as you like and attach them to the `Mediator` instance. Bear in mind that this isn't a specific mediator, in that many instances can be attached, in most cases it's better to be explicit with which classes can be attached rather than allowing dynamic registration by a key.

```
$scheduler = new EventScheduler();
$user = new User();

$scheduler->attach('user', $user);

// Now we know that we can get the mediator from the User class
$user->getMediator();

// We can also get the User from the mediator itself.
$scheduler->getAttached('user');
```

As you attach more classes you'll notice that each of them can use their mediator to get instances of the other attached classes, this is where the concept of one good friend comes from.

This is just an example and not fully featured for brevity, but should give you a good idea why using common design patterns will help you enormously and is a very good place to start when learning OOP if you want to develop good habits.